# Cannot ssh to VPN using Command Prompt or putty, can from PHPStorm & Git Bash?

Tags: bash, ssh, vpn, git, putty

So, I'm trying to connect to a VPN I own using my `forge` user. I can `ssh` through Git Bash and PHPStorm's Database Connection tool, yet I cannot from Command Prompt or putty.

If I try to run this from the cmd: `ssh myuser@myip -v`, I get this as the result:

[image]

Likewise, if I try to `ssh` in from putty, I get a dialog telling me:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: public key)

Yet, using Git Bash:

[image]

Success!

Why? What's different? Is this a file permissions issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are using really old version of ssh. Version 4.6 is more than 10 years old. You should update (current is 7.1).

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: public key)

Also Putty can by probably updated. But the problem with putty is that you probably didn't set the public key that putty should use. Similar problem is with the first screenshot -- there are different paths to identity file. If you change them to the real path of your authentication keys, it should work fine (there should be `IdentityFile` option is `ssh_config` or `-i` switch of `ssh`).

Comment: Hmm. How can I update ssh? I can't seem to find any viable download links. Also, setting the -i switch did work! Thanks! But how can I change to the working value as a default?

Comment: That is what IdentityFile option is for. You can add this option to your ~/.ssh/config file

Answer (score 0):

check sshd_config for AllowUser and DenyUsers and Allow your user for connect to ssh server

Tutorial : 
To allow only the users Fred and Wilma to connect to your computer, add the following line to the bottom of the sshd_config file:

AllowUsers Fred Wilma

To allow everyone except the users Dino and Pebbles to connect to your computer, add the following line to the bottom of the sshd_config file:

DenyUsers Dino Pebbles